# Webapps and Smart Card Interaction

Tags: java, web-applications, javacard

A few weeks ago, I tried to ask a similar question, but phrased it incorrectly, so I'm trying again. I still don't think what I want is possible, but I'm asking anyhow.

Given a web application running on a "remote" server (i.e. can be anywhere in the world), can that webapp communicate with applets on a Java Card connected to a user's workstation? Or phrased separately, can said remote webapp issue ADPU commands (say, through the middleware installed on the user's workstation).

Answer (score 2):

You can write a TimedTask (Thread) on the applet to transfer(submit) the data you want from the client machine to the server on a timed basis.

Have a look at the [Apache HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/). This will enable you to send requests to your server in the same manner a browser does.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm trying to interact with applets on the Java card that already exist, so a TimedTask isn't an option.

Comment: Is there no way to extend the current classes/applets? Are the classes final? If you can extend, extend and call the super class with the your timed sub-class.

Comment: As smart cards play a passive role in any communication and are slaves always, I think this answer is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Hi
i had same scenario , which i have created the jApplet and embedded it in jsp, all the functionality of communicating is in the jApplet, which could Interact with SmartCard , after Interaction that could send the result to server !